# Capturing video from an external source through a capture card in Windows XP

Tags: video, windows-xp

I've a capture card Pinnacle PCTV and I need to use it in Windows Xp; the constraint is that I need to record the video coming from the external source in **full screen**. The pinnacle software can do it only in a non full screen mode. Can you suggest me any software able to do that please?

[image]

Comment: What is full screen in your case? What resolution do you want to record and are you sure this is not simply a hardware limitation of the used capture card? As we are talking about WinXP may be a virtual machine would be easier as it could be captured without any hardware.

Comment: Hello @Robert for example I've a videotape reader. When I connect it to my capture card I'd like to see the video in full screen on my monitor. I know that other softwares (OBS etc.; it is not compatible with Windows XP) have this option.